# compound queries (composed from separate sources) in basex

Tags: xml, database, nosql, xquery, basex

I am trying to conceive of a way to use BaseX to process a compound query that incorporates an external query.

The core idea is a very simple application, expressed as an XQuery file, that results in the following sequence of actions:

1. Extraction of data from a database, by some query.
2. Modification of the  results of (1), by some query.
3. Persistence of the   results from (2), back into the database from which the data was originally extracted.

The modifications given in (2) would be external to the application, supplied per invocation in a separate file, or in a command-line parameter.

Thus, the overall query would entail static components, the fixed parts of the application, represented by (1) and (3), and dynamic components, passed by the invocation, represented by (2).

I realize such a processing pipeline may be achieved through queries supplied in a full application accessing the database by one of the  language-specific APIs, but I am trying to consider an approach that requires use only of XQuery statements.

Does the design of BaseX accommodate an application having the structure as described?

Comment: I'd rather recommend a different approach by leveraging a suitable ETL tool (like Pentaho, Talend, CloverDX, Informatica, etc) that supports data scenarios like this (a database-specific ODBC driver or similar may be needed if the ETL tool does not offer a native connection to your DB.

Comment: Well, modules can be used in XQuery and certainly in BaseX. If you need dynamic XQuery evaluation in BaseX then look into https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module but your description does it make it clear whether your second module can't simply imported like a normal XQuery module.

Comment: @Martin: The complete operation integrates a custom query supplied per invocation into a broader work flow with static elements. The "second module" cannot be one referred by the first as a static import, because it has no fixed form. Overall, the operation is like a visit to restaurant. Waiting to be seated and paying the bill are static parts of the procedure, but a different dish may be ordered each time.